# Regarding the RegEX

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression where it should allow only one value after decimal point. The one which I have written is:

```
(N\/A)(n\/a)|\d+.?\d{0,1}
```

It is accepting the values as per my requirement but the problem is it is also accepting `1.` - i.e., if I am not giving value after decimal also it is accepting.

Comment: You can use `\d+(.\d)?` I guess.

Comment: Thank you so much it is working fine.

Comment: @Wickramaranga you need to escape `.` e.g. `\d+(\.\d)?` otherwise it will accept any character e.g. `123a4`. Furthermore you are now capturing the first decimal, no matter how many exist. I've added a suggested edit to match only single digit numbers.

Comment: @Skogsv yeah. :) My bad. That has to be `\d+(\.\d)?`.

Comment: @Wickramaranga Sure thing! Although you are still matching the first decimal point, no matter how many decimals exist. I'm not sure if OP wanted this or to only match if there is a single decimal.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Wickramaranga's answer which extracts the first digit after a decimal point if you wish to only match on numbers you can use lookarounds:

```
(?<!\.)\b\d+(?:\.(\d))?\b(?!\.)
```

This will extract the first digit (not including the point) as well as ensure that the number only has one digit.

Note that this also includes any number with no decimals.

In order to require there to be one and only one digit:

```
(?<!\.)\b\d+\.(\d)\b(?!\.)
```